# authentication dialog does not appear

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying use the facebook outh system to get some basic info from my user.
The problem is that when the user logs in it does not ask for any permissions. it provides a login dialog but thats it no dialog like this:
[image: permissions dialog]
On my app settings I've set the authentication to the following:

[image: app settings]

So what am I missing here?
You should be able to see the dialog here: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=388123757870529&redirect_uri=http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

Kristian,

It looks like you need to correctly setup your app domain (localhost) and your website url (http://localhost) because right now, the link you provided is giving this error:

"The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."

Comment: Try https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=388123757870529&redirect_uri=http://dacora.localhost which is what it is set up for in the config